# bash script grep the etc file for user information

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to write a script in bash to read in arguments (usernames) and then return information about that username by searching the /etc/passwd file. I am not the root on the server that I am scripting this on, but I don't need to be. Here is the code that I have so far, but I dont think I am using the grep command right.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then #if num of args =1; then continue on
        UNAME=$1 #set arg to var UNAME
        grep UNAME=$(grep $/etc/passwd)
        if [ $UNAME == /etc/passwd ]; then #if UNAME exists then display info below
                echo "-------------------------------------------"
                echo "Username:       $(grep UNAME/etc/passwd/ $f1) "
                echo "User ID (UID):  $(grep UNAME/etc/passwd/) "
                echo "Group ID (GID): $(grep UNAME/etc/passwd/) "
                echo "User info:      $(grep UNAME/etc/passwd/) "
                echo "Home directory: $(grep UNAME/etc/passwd/) "
                echo "Command shell:  $(grep UNAME/etc/passwd/) "
                echo "-------------------------------------------"
        else #if UNAME is nonexistant then display this error message
                echo "-------------------------------------------"
                echo ""$UNAME" does not exist."
                echo "-------------------------------------------"
        fi
fi
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then #if num of args =0; then display this
        echo "Not enough arguments provided."
        echo "USAGE: $0 <user_name> [user_name] ..."
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: If you're on Linux, then your OS probably provides a tool made for this specific purpose -- `getent` -- which will work not only with `/etc/passwd` but also with network sources such as LDAP, NIS, Active Directory, etc. `getent passwd username` will return the entry for `username` whether that's just a filesystem retrieval or a network lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I get to the explanation, here is how I would have written your script:

```
cat ./test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

UNAME=${1} #set arg to var UNAME
if [ -z ${UNAME} ]; then #if no argument is provided; then display this
    echo "Not enough arguments provided."
    echo "USAGE: $0 <user_name>" 
    exit 1
fi
if grep ${UNAME} /etc/passwd >/dev/null; then #if UNAME exists then display info below
    echo "-------------------------------------------"
    echo "Username:       $(awk -F ':' -v uname=${UNAME} '$0 ~ uname {print $1}' /etc/passwd)"
    echo "User ID (UID):  $(awk -F ':' -v uname=${UNAME} '$0 ~ uname {print $3}' /etc/passwd)"
    echo "Group ID (GID): $(awk -F ':' -v uname=${UNAME} '$0 ~ uname {print $4}' /etc/passwd)"
    echo "User info:      $(awk -F ':' -v uname=${UNAME} '$0 ~ uname {print $5}' /etc/passwd)"
    echo "Home directory: $(awk -F ':' -v uname=${UNAME} '$0 ~ uname {print $6}' /etc/passwd)"
    echo "Command shell:  $(awk -F ':' -v uname=${UNAME} '$0 ~ uname {print $7}' /etc/passwd)"
    echo "-------------------------------------------"
else #if UNAME is nonexistant then display this error message
    echo "-------------------------------------------"
    echo "\"${UNAME}\" does not exist."
    echo "-------------------------------------------"
fi
```

Explanation:

- `if` can use `grep` directly to check for the existence of
  your argument in passwd
- `UNAME=` is how arguments are assigned, not
  called - they are called with the $ - for example `$UNAME`
- `/etc/passwd` is an absolute file name and not an argument, thus
  `$/etc/passwd` doesn't mean anything to bash
- `argument=$(any old bash command)` is telling bash that you want to
  assign the output of "any old bash command" to "argument", so `$()`
  has to contain a command with output for "argument" to be assigned
  anything.
- the `>/dev/null` sends the output of `grep` to the waste basket because we only care at this point whether or not it's successful so that `if` knows what to do
- `grep` works like this: `grep <the thing you want to find> <file>` (note that spaces matter and to use "" if you want to include spaces in your search)
- to get specific fields, `awk` is more useful. `awk -F':'` tells awk that I want `:` to define my field separators; `-v uname=${UNAME}` passes my argument to awk; within awk, `$0 ~ uname` checks the line for my argument (like grep); and `{print $1}` prints the first field, and so on

Also consider the limitation of partial matches. If, for example, I have a user JSmith and Smith, searching Smith will return both. This can be addressed with regex but will add a great deal of complexity to the script.

Here is a version with lighter awk usage which works with multiple arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
for username; do
    if grep ${username} /etc/passwd >/dev/null; then #if username exists then display info below
        echo "---------------------------------------"
        awk -F':' -v uname="${username}" '\
            $0 ~ uname \
            {print " Username:         "$1\
                "\n User ID (UID):    "$3\
                "\n Group ID (GID):   "$4\
                "\n User info:        "$5\
                "\n Home directory:   "$6\
                "\n Command shell:    "$7}' /etc/passwd
        echo "---------------------------------------"
    else #if username is nonexistant then display this error message
        echo "---------------------------------------"
        echo "\"${username}\" does not exist."
        echo "---------------------------------------"
    fi
done

if [ -z ${1} ]; then #if no argument is provided; then display this
    echo " Not enough arguments provided."
    echo " USAGE: $0 <user name>" 
    exit 1
fi
```

*Credit to William Pursell for explaining the for loop

Comment: Running `awk` 6 times to parse a single line? That's crazy inefficient.

Comment: ...and as a much larger issue, `[ -z ${1} ]` doesn't work the way you think it does. If `$1` is empty, it becomes `[ -z ]` -- which tests whether `"-z"` is a non-empty string, which it is, so it returns true; on the other hand, that'll also return true for the string `foo -o 1 = 1`. To **truly** test whether `$1` is empty, you want `[ -z "$1" ]`, **with the quotes**.

Comment: I'm not bothered by it for something this small. If I had more time on this I would have done it all in one awk. but while I was writing what I did, William provided a much better answer than mine.

Comment: Sprinkling extra curly braces everywhere doesn't do anything to make your code more correct. Sprinkling *quotes* everywhere would. `grep "$UNAME"`, for instance.

Comment: The other thing is that POSIX convention on variable names specifies all-caps names for variables with meaning to the OS or shell, and reserves lower-case names for application use. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace (setting the former will overwrite the latter if one exists with the same name).

Comment: Thanks Charles, I wasn't sprinkling, just doing it out of habit.

Comment: How would this need to be modified if the script was ran with more than one argument (multiple usernames)

Comment: You could do it by making a list from all arguments and iterating over them in a for loop. When I get a chance I can edit my answer to include it.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing too much.  grep is the wrong tool for the type of parsing you are trying to do.  The solution given here is pretty sloppy since it reads the passwd file once for each user you are querying instead of reporting everything in one pass, but it's not unreasonable:

```
#!/bin/sh

for UNAME; do
        while IFS=: read login passwd uid gid name home shell; do
                if test "$login" = "$UNAME"; then
                        echo "-------------------------------------------"
                        echo "Username:       $login"
                        echo "User ID (UID):  $uid"
                        echo "Group ID (GID): $gid"
                        echo "User info:      $name"
                        echo "Home directory: $home"
                        echo "Command shell:  $shell"
                        echo "-------------------------------------------"
                        continue 2
                fi
        done < /etc/passwd
        echo "No entry for user $UNAME" >&2
done
```

Comment: I'm intrigued. I understand the IFS=: and the while read...;done < /etc/passwd, but it works without ${1}. I have something to learn here. Is it the way "for" works?

Comment: the 'continue 2' is new to me, too. I understand what happens without it, but not why.

Comment: The `for var; do` construction is equivalent to `for var in "$@"; do` and iterates over all the command line arguments.

Comment: The `continue 2` continues the for loop (the 2 defines the loop as the 2nd enclosing loop, so that it doesn't just continue the while loop).  It probably would be clearer just to write `break` to break out of the while loop.  Not really sure why I used continue.

Comment: Oh, right.  You can't just break out of the while loop, because then the error message would be printed every time.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool to read databases such as `passwd` is `getent`. This will fetch entries from a database supported by Name Service Switch Libraries. If you really need to limit reading the files databases, you can tell `getent` to use `files` database with `-s files`.

Your code is unnecessarily long. Fetching a record and parsing them into multiple variables should be enough.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then #if num of args =1; then continue on
    if IFS=: read username ignore uid gid gecos home shell < <(getent -s files passwd $1); then
                echo "-------------------------------------------"
                echo "Username:       $username"
                echo "User ID (UID):  $uid"
                echo "Group ID (GID): $gid"
                echo "User info:      $gecos"
                echo "Home directory: $home"
                echo "Command shell:  $shell"
                echo "-------------------------------------------"
        else #if $1 is nonexistant then display this error message
                echo "-------------------------------------------"
                echo "'$1' does not exist."
                echo "-------------------------------------------"
        fi
fi
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then #if num of args =0; then display this
        echo "Not enough arguments provided."
        echo "USAGE: $0 <user_name> [user_name] ..."
        exit 1
fi
```